# epsilon delta question limit questions

Tags: calculus

I have two quick questions. In calculus books when proving limits, I always see something like, let $\delta = \min(\delta_{1}, \delta_{2})$. Does this mean that we take a $\delta$ such that it contains both $\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$?

Comment: $\min(a,b)$ is a symbol whose value is the smaller of the two numbers $a$ and $b$.  In your application, it probably means we are taking a ball of radius $\delta$, which should be contained in both balls of radii $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ are just numbers. So min($\delta_1$, $\delta_2$) is just the minimum, i.e., min$(1,2) = 1$.

Comment: I see. What is the reasoning for choosing the smaller one?

Comment: if, say, $|x-a| < \delta_2 \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$, then also $|x-a| < \delta_1 < \delta_2 \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$. But, if $|x-a| < \delta_1 \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$, then maybe for $\delta_1 < |x-a| < \delta_2$ it does not imply $|f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$. So choosing a smaller, positive $\delta$ in an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof, the proof still holds.

Comment: $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ is precisely the most easily available and  "optimal" choice to guarantee that $\delta>0$ and also that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies both $|x-y|<\delta_1$ and $|x-y|<\delta_2$.

Answer (score 1):

No, we choose the smaller one. $\delta, \delta_1, \delta_2$ represent various numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

You take the smaller of $\delta$s. Usually one of them is a "safety", protecting against too large an $\epsilon$ and the other depends explicitly on $\epsilon$